# Problem with "npm" installation in VS Code - tried different ways, no result

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm-install

The error:

```
C:\\Users\\RC\>npm install -g @angular/cli
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
const err = new Error(message);
^

Error: Cannot find module './utils/unsupported.js'
Require stack:

- C:\\Users\\RC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js
- C:\\Users\\RC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js
  \[90m    at Function.Module.\_resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)\[39m
  \[90m    at Function.Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)\[39m
  \[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)\[39m
  \[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)\[39m
  at module.exports (C:\\Users\\RC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\\[4mnpm\[24m\\lib\\cli.js:14:59)
  at Object.\<anonymous\> (C:\\Users\\RC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\\[4mnpm\[24m\\bin\\npm-cli.js:2:25)
  \[90m    at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)\[39m
  \[90m    at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)\[39m
  \[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)\[39m
  \[90m    at Function.Module.\_load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)\[39m {
  code: \[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'\[39m,
  requireStack: \[
  \[32m'C:\\Users\\RC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js'\[39m,
  \[32m'C:\\Users\\RC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'\[39m
  \]
  }

C:\\Users\\RC\>npm install -g @angular/cli
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
const err = new Error(message);
^

Error: Cannot find module './utils/unsupported.js'
Require stack:

- C:\\Users\\RC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js
- C:\\Users\\RC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install Node.js, then also npm is installed. That might be the easiest to do.

You can download Node.js here:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

VS Code then finds npm, no further setup is required.